# product object showing last product data in magento2

Tags: magento2, product

I am just trying to load a product and displaying its values but facing an issue -

Here is my code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get ('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2135);
echo "<pre>"; echo $product->getId().'======'.$product->getSellerId();
$product = '';
$product = $objectManager->get ('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2140);
echo "<pre>"; echo $product->getId().'======'.$product->getSellerId();
```

Here product '2135' have seller_id so its printing right value but product '2140' didn't have SellerId but its printing last product's sellerId value here.

Don't know why it's behaving like this. I am  using Magento2.1.6.

even if I changed the product object parameter to $product_1 and loading product 2140 after 2135 its showing seller_id in 2140 - here is my code -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get ('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2135);
echo "<pre>"; echo $product->getId().'======'.$product->getSellerId();
$product = '';
$product_1 = $objectManager->get ('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2140);
echo "<pre>"; echo $product_1->getId().'======'.$product_1->getSellerId();
```

Result -
2135======1450

2140======1450

Expected result -

2135======1450

2140======

Please let me know what going wrong over here.

Comment: Don't load the product 2135, only load 1450 and check if it results correctly or not?

Comment: Yes if I load only product '2140' then its not giving 'SellerId' for 2140..But issue is coming when I am loading after any product that have vale for "seller_id" attribute...

Comment: @Atul check my answer with explanation. I hope it will clear your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `get()` method of `ObjectManager` class to get a product instance i.e. `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`, and this method follows the `Singleton` pattern which means if there is already an instance for a particular class, it will return back the existing instance instead of creating a new one.

So either you can use `create()` method or use `unsetData()` method to reset the existing data before loading a new product.

However, use of an`ObjectManager` class directly is strongly discouraged. You should use `__construct()` to inject your dependancies.

Here is the sample code for the same. I'm using Block class for example, you can use the same code in any class.

```
<?php
namespace {Namespace}\{Module}\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProduct($productId)
    {

        return $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2135);
echo "<pre>"; echo $product->getId().'======'.$product->getSellerId();

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2140);
echo "<pre>"; echo $product->getId().'======'.$product->getSellerId();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2135);
echo $product->getSellerId();

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(2140);
echo $product->getSellerId();
```

You need to use `create` a method in this case because.

**Get:** first tries to find shared instance (already created), if it's not found - it just creates new shared instance

**Create:** `create` method creating the new object and returns the new object.

Maybe you are getting same value because a second product has no value.